# Movement of classic dipole oriented obliquely in electric field

Tags: electrostatics, rotational-dynamics

If a classical electrical dipole (+q, -q) pointing in direction (1,1,1) and originally at rest is placed in a uniform electric field, but at an oblique angle so that the electric field is directed along one axis, say x axis (1,0,0), how will the dipole move?  Because the dipole doesn't initially have angular momentum, I'm not sure that this is described as precession, but I'm not certain.   I think that the motion is complex but I don't know how to begin to approach this.  I'm ignoring any relativity issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the net force on the dipole is zero, it should just spin in the plane, formed by the dipole vector and the electric field vector. The applied torque and, therefore, the angular acceleration will depend on the angle between these two vectors.